# MrSID on QGIS 2.10 Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, mrsid

I have QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa and GDAL 1.11.2, and I can't open MrSID (.sid) images en QGIS, I have lost three days trying to make it work, but I can't make it.

My Linux is 14.04 trusty tahr.

Comment: as I recall you can't run the proprietary libraries for MrSID on Linux otherwise try this link for Windows: http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/mrsid/

Comment: Ubuntugis unstable had support for MrSid with GDAL 1.9.0 for Ubuntu Oneiric and lucid. Unfortunately, nobody has built newer packages.